# What's the reading order of the God Eater manga?

Tags: god-eater

I wanted to read God Eater manga but I found that there are quite a lot of manga series in the franchise. What is the reading order of these manga?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **What is the reading order of these manga?**

Read them in the **order they were published in**.

Some may not know but God Eater indeed has a manga.

It has, but the manga itself is **based on the original game**, so **it has nothing to do with the anime**. (The anime itself is different because of the MC)

AFAIK, there are 4 mangas and here is a brief description:

- [Return of the Messiah](http://godeater.wikia.com/wiki/God_Eater:_Return_of_the_Messiah) -> takes place in the original GE timeline

  > The story takes place in Fenrir America Branch, 1 year after the events of God Eater Burst.
- [Spiral Fate](http://godeater.wikia.com/wiki/God_Eater:_The_Spiral_Fate) -> takes place after the GE timeline

  > a manga that offers an alternate reality to the main continuity of the God Eater series, since the protagonist is Ryo Kagami, not Yu Kannagi.
- [Summer Wars](http://godeater.wikia.com/wiki/God_Eater:_The_Summer_Wars) -> side story about romance & stuff

  > Alisa Illinichina Amiella develops a feeling similar to respect for the 1st Unit leader, Yu Kannagi. Meanwhile, Alisa and Yu are dispatched to Aegis Island on a protection mission.
- [2nd Break](http://godeater.wikia.com/wiki/God_Eater_-the_2nd_break-)-> takes place in the GE2 timeline

  > The manga is a prequel to God Eater 2 in the manga continuity.

The protagonist of each manga is different though, and it seems like they only appeared exclusively on that manga.

Here are the Mangas in other of [Publication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gods_Eater_Burst):

> The game received several manga adaptations written by Namco Bandai. The first is titled God Eater: Kyūseishu no Kikan (GOD EATER - God Eater -Return of the Messaiah) was illustrated by Osan Eijii, published by Kodansha, and serialized in Rival Comics magazine. As of December 28, 2011, the series was completed and compiled into five volumes.[^](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gods_Eater_Burst#cite_note-21) The second is titled God Eater: the spiral fate and was illustrated by Saito Rokuro, published by Dengeki Comics and serialized in Side-B.N Magazine. As of November 27, 2010, the manga was completed and compiled into two volumes. A third manga titled God Eater: the summer wars was illustrated by Okiura, published by Kadokawa Shoten and serialized in Dragon Age Comics Magazine. The series was completed and compiled into a single volume on May 7, 2012.

[God Eater 2nd Break](http://myanimelist.net/manga/46128/God_Eater__The_2nd_Break)

> was Published: Dec 27, 2011 to Aug 27, 2013 with 3 Volumes and 18 chapters